# ¿Como agregar una condicion de inicio de sesion en codigo java/jsp, netbeans, phpmyadmin, mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, netbeans, jsp

He realizado una aplicación web que consta de una pagina de inicio de sesión, donde coloque como condiciones que el usuario y la contraseña estén conectados a una base de datos y sea verificado que estos sean exactamente iguales a los colocados en la base de datos, coloco el ejemplo de codigo:

```
<%
      Connection con = null;
      Statement st = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      Encriptar enc=new Encriptar();
      if (request.getParameter("login") != null) {
          String email = request.getParameter("email");
          String password = request.getParameter("password");
          HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
          try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/proyecto?user=xxxxx&password=xxxxxxx");
                  st = con.createStatement();
                  rs = st.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM `user` where email='" + email + "' and password1='" + enc. getMD5(password) + "'; ");
              while (rs.next()) {
                  sesion.setAttribute("logueado", "1");
                  sesion.setAttribute("email", rs.getString("email"));
                  sesion.setAttribute("id", rs.getString("id"));
                  response.sendRedirect("premiumPost.jsp");
              }
              out.print(" <div class=\"alert alert-dark\" role=\"alert\"> Usuario no valido </div>");
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
      }
  %>
```

la pagina funciona muy bien a excepción de que quiero agregarle una condición mas, que la columna pago en la base de datos tambien sea verificada y que solo permita el acceso a aquellos que tengan el email, contraseña y pago verificados en la base de datos, para eso coloque una tabla llamada pago que solo aceptara dos caracteres "si" o "no". Pero lo he intentado de mil maneras y no he podido realizar la conexion para que me homologue esos datos. supongo que el problema esta en que no se agregar los atributos de pago en la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
 rs = st.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM `user` where email='" + email + "' and password1='" + enc. getMD5(password) + "'; ");
```

ya que aqui es donde verifico que los datos de la base de datos y los que he colocado en mi pagina sean los mismo. al ser codigo sql trabajo poco con ello y me siento todavia un novato trabajando con JAVA. voy a colocar el codigo completo y la forma en que esta organizada mi base de datos:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="Utils.Encriptar"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <head>
    <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="premiumPost.jsp">Premium Post</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.jsp">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="register.jsp">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form method="post" action="login.jsp" >
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
        <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
        <label> </label>
      </form>
      <%
          Connection con = null;
          Statement st = null;
          ResultSet rs = null;
          Encriptar enc=new Encriptar();
          if (request.getParameter("login") != null) {
              String email = request.getParameter("email");
              String password = request.getParameter("password");
              HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
              try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/proyecto?user=xxx&password=xxxx");
                      st = con.createStatement();
                      rs = st.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM `user` where email='" + email + "' and password1='" + enc. getMD5(password) + "'; ");
                  while (rs.next()) {
                      sesion.setAttribute("logueado", "1");
                      sesion.setAttribute("email", rs.getString("email"));
                      sesion.setAttribute("id", rs.getString("id"));
                      response.sendRedirect("premiumPost.jsp");
                  }
                  out.print(" <div class=\"alert alert-dark\" role=\"alert\"> Usuario no valido </div>");
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
          }
      %>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2023 My Blog</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

También había pensado crearme una base de datos opcional donde pudiera pasar a estas personas que realizaron los pagos o otra tabla y que el login y el registro no compartieran la misma base de datos, pero de igual forma peco por no saber como organizar los elementos con mysql y java/jsp.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He conseguido la solucion gracias a un usuario que me ha dado informacion fuera del canal, es la siguiente:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='" + email + "' AND password1='" + enc.getMD5(password) + "' AND pago='SI';");
```

era simplemente agregar una condición mas, pero al no saber como se desarrolla la sintaxis no sabia exactamente como colocarla.

Comment: Buenas, la siguiente información no tiene que ver con tu pregunta, pero te recomiendo que utilices sentencias con PreparedStatement, ya que actualmente tu inicio de sesión es vulnerable a ataques de tipo inyección SQL.

Comment: hola @Maida gracias, he realizado un código mucho mas seguro y realice unas consultas preparadas y después me percate que podía realizarlo todo con bibliotecas que le dan mas seguridad. Gracias por tu consejo.